# Python/sqlite: get PK of newly inserted row

Tags: python, sql

I am inserting a row using raw SQL and need to get the Primary key of the newly inserted row. I cannot assume that any of the non-PK inserted data are unique nor can I assume that the row is the last inserted row.

If it's not possible using raw SQL, how about with "regular" inserts? I am thinking that I will have to create a new customID field altogether. I would then create a random number variable and insert this as the unique ID. Since I inserted it, I know what it is. But that seems to defeat the purpose of having the PK as a unique identifier. Is there a way to pull the next ID of a sequence (as in Oracle)?

```
insert_sql = "insert into my_table(title, text) values ('the title', 'the text')"

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert_sql)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... nor can I assume that the row is the last inserted row.

Globally, you cannot assume it. But related to your connection, you can - so you can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` or just `cursor.connection.insert_id()`. Maybe even `cursor.lastrowid`, but I'm not sure if it that would work as well.

Comment: Thanks! cursor.lastrowid worked beautifully. And it's local. cursor.connection.insert_id() gave me an error: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'insert_id'

Comment: !!!Apparently insert_id method is now obsolete and lastrowid must be used: https://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70461/thread/f3987b9f/